# Flow Layout Panel issues when adding group box controls dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of group box controls and i need to display only few questions in the flow layout panel but it is not displaying properly(width and height reduced) but if I add that controls to the form it is displaying properly
here is my code. please help me how to get back from this problem

code of flow layout panel(displyQues)

```
private void getQuestions(int quesid)
{
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = quesid; i <= lstgrpques.Count; i++)
        {
            displyQues.Location = new Point(15, 30);
            displyQues.Show();
            displyQues.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1218, 620);
            displyQues.AutoScroll = true;
            lstgrpques[i - 1].Show();
            displyQues.WrapContents = false;
            displyQues.Controls.Add(lstgrpques[i - 1]);
            displyQues.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
            qstnId++;
            j++;
            if (j == 5)
            {
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

code of group box

```
 foreach (var question in questions)
 {
   int QustTxtHght = 0;
   GroupBox QuesAnsoptn = new GroupBox();
   QuesAnsoptn.Hide();
   QuesAnsoptn.AutoSize = true;
   QuesAnsoptn.Width = 820;
   QuesAnsoptn.Location = new Point(15, QustHgt);
   var quest = question.Attribute("ques").Value.Trim();
   if (quest.Contains('{'))
   {
   quest = GetFormatCode(quest);
   QustTxtHght = quest.Length +40;
   }
   else
    QustTxtHght = 15;

   QuesAnsoptn.Text = question.Attribute("id").Value + ". " + quest;
   QuesAnsoptn.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);

   var options = question.Descendants("option");
   var optHgt = 0;
   foreach (var option in options)
   {
    RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton();
    rdbtn.AutoSize = true;
    rdbtn.Location = new Point(20, QustTxtHght + optHgt + 10);
    rdbtn.Name = k.ToString();
    lstRdOptns.Add(rdbtn);
    rdbtn.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
    var opt = option.Value;
    var loc = 0;
    if (opt.Contains('{'))
     {
       opt = GetFormatCode(opt);
       loc = opt.Length + 40;
     }
    else { loc = rdbtn.Size.Height; }
    rdbtn.Text = opt;
    optHgt = loc + optHgt;
    QuesAnsoptn.Controls.Add(rdbtn);
    }
    k++;
    this.Controls.Add(QuesAnsoptn);
    QustHgt = QuesAnsoptn.Size.Height + QustHgt + 20;
    QuesAnsoptn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(820,QuesAnsoptn.Size.Height);
    lstgrpques.Add(QuesAnsoptn);
  }
```

Comment: `QuesAnsoptn.AutoSize = false;`

Comment: sir ...if i will keep autosize property  to false means then it will not display the full Question and options

Comment: Your code was setting the width and the height of that control, so it seemed like you didn't really want to have it auto size for you.  Did you try it?